# select first non-null row with minimum date (Big Query)

Tags: sql, date, select, google-bigquery, window-functions

I want to select the first non-null row with the minimum date. I'll like to use a CASE WHEN that condition is met, then 1 ELSE 0.

[image]

So more like CASE WHEN row IS NOT and DATE is minimum DATE then 1 ELSE 0. I just need to select ONLY one row.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 0 AS marker FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE item_count IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *, IF(1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date), 1, 0)
FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE NOT item_count IS NULL
ORDER BY user, date
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
select 
    t.*
    case when date = min(case when itemcount is not null then date end) over(partition by user order by date)
        then 1
        else 0
    end as marker
from mytable t
```

I am unsure whether BigQuery supports `minif()` as a window function:

```
select 
    t.*
    case when date = minif(date, itemcount is not null) over(partition by user order by date)
        then 1
        else 0
    end as marker
from mytable
```

Comment: The first with the MIN function worked. MINIF not available for google Bigquery now